# Search if user has account on Office 365?

Tags: c#, office365, exchangewebservices, office365api

We have a situation where we have both, our in-house Exchange server and Office 365. I need to search from email address, whether the account exists on in-house server or Office 365. How can we do it through EWS?

Answer (score 0):

Autodiscover will return the correct endpoints to access a given mailbox provided that you've configured it correctly for a hybrid environment.  I haven't done this myself but there should be documentation online.